# Get Shopware 6 Current LoggedIn Customer or Guest

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I would like to get the current logged in customer data into my Symfony/Shopware 6 service. How do I do it. What specific service/class do I inject?

I am working with Shopware 6 Number Range entity, I am creating a new Number Range. The number range is independent of the customer entity but I want to access the customer entity or order entity when generating a new order number or customer number.

For example:

```php
class FreeShopping
{
  public function __construct(C**** $currentCustomer){
   $this->currentCustomer =  $currentCustomer
  }

  public function eligibleForFreeShopping(){

   if($this->currentCustomer->name === 'Hermann'){
    return true;
   }

   return false;

  }

}
```

```xml
<service id="FreeShopping">
 <argument id="**/**/CurrentCustomer" type="service">
<service>
```

Comment: I do not want to use an event or go through with a storefront controller

Answer (score -1):

*(not really a full answer, but to much for a comment)*

You write in the comment, that you do not want to use a storefront controller or event. Whenever, I think you should pass it from there.

The current customer is stored in the `\Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext` (`->getCustomer()`)

So your service must be called from somewhere, either a controller or an event where you have the context available.

I believe there is no super global which stores the context, if there would be, it would also be hard to integration- oder unit-test.

Feel free to update the question with more info, why you can't pass this in from an event.

Comment: My question has been updated